# C++14 - error: invalid types 'int[int]' for array subscript v[x].push_back(y) in vector while implementing graph

Tags: vector, graph, implementation, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

I face this problem many times when i implement the Graph data-structure in c++14 via vector, I search a lot but it could not help me because it gives me search results about array though i want vector's solution. Please help me to solve this Error.

I got an error in -> positions define below,

```
for(ll i=0;i<m;i++)
{
    cin>>x>>y;
 ->   v[x].push_back(y);
 ->   v[y].push_back(x);
}


#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
#define ll int
vector<ll> v[300005];
bool vis[300005];
vector<ll> vv[300005];
void dfs(int s,int p);
int main()
{

    ll n,m,u,v;
    cin>>n>>u>>v;
    ll x,y;
    m=n-1;
    for(ll i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
        cin>>x>>y;
        v[x].push_back(y);
        v[y].push_back(x);
    }

    for(ll i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        memset(vis,0,vis[0]*n);
        dfs(i,i);
    }

    ll ans=0;
    ll o=(n*(n-1))/2;
    ll p=0;bool fu=0,fv=0;
    for(ll i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        p=0;fu=0;fv=0;
        for(ll j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            if(fu && vv[i][j]==v){
                fv=1;break;
            }
            if(vv[i][j]==u) fu=1;
            if(fu) p++;
        }
        ans+=o-(n-p);
    }
    cout<<ans;    
    return 0;
}
void dfs(int s,int p)
{
    vis[s]=1;vv[p].push_back(s);
    for(ll i=0;i<v[s].size();i++)
    {
        if(vis[v[s][i]]==0) //Very IMP - vis[v[s][i]]
            dfs(v[s][i],p);
    }
}
```

I got an error as :

29:12: `error: invalid types 'int[int]' for array subscript
         v[x].push_back(y);`
30:12: `error: invalid types 'int[int]' for array subscript
         v[y].push_back(x);`

But i Expect the result correctly, because i trace it and i could not find any errors in my code. Please Give Solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have declared two variables of type v; one inside main of type int and second outside main of type vector. The code inside the for loop is referring to v of type int. Either change the name of either of the two variables or use scope resolution operator :: to access the global variable.

```
for(ll i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
        cin>>x>>y;
        ::v[x].push_back(y);
        ::v[y].push_back(x);
    }
```